# How to deal with a person that consistently misuses the squat rack?

Tags: workout, gym

There's a guy at my gym who I see fairly consistently. He doesn't exactly work out in the traditional sense, but alternates between stretching routines and doing a small handful of karate kicks/punches. I've yet to see him touch a weight, resistance machine, or do any cardio (aside from his karate). This is all well and good; I don't really care what this guy does to get his exercise, except for one small detail - he performs 100% of this routine IN THE SQUAT RACK. We only have two squat racks at my gym and they're heavily used. As far as I can tell, there's absolutely no need for this guy to use a squat rack to get his routine done. My question is: can I (or gym staff) do anything to discourage this behavior? I find it extremely inconsiderate on his part to make people wait to use the rack while he does a routine that, frankly, could easily be accomplished at home.

Comment: If you, as a gym member, have noticed his behavior, than I'm certain that others have as well, including the staff. I wouldn't recommend you talking to him personally, but if the staff don't talk to him about his behavior, then talk to the staff. If the staff simply hasn't noticed this yet, you mentioning it to them could prompt them to watch for the behavior and intervene if necessary.

Comment: If he's unnecessarily taking up something you need (the squat rack), you could try to **politely** ask him if you can use it. If you feel uncomfortable doing this or if he refuses, let the staff know and they can take care of it. Otherwise, it's not really your job to police what this guy does if it isn't interfering with what you need to do or making you uncomfortable.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has very little to do with fitness and everything to do with how to confront someone. Maybe https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @SeanDuggan I agree this question would work on interpersonal stackexchange but I asked it here because I also wanted the fitness community's opinion/answer on whether or not this behavior is acceptable or not. I don't think what he's doing is OK and that's why I want to know how to deal with him, however, my world-view may be warped - other gym-goers could maybe tell me that "he got to it first, he can do what he wants so you can't do anything about it." There's definitely an element of gym etiquette in my question so I'd prefer to have it answered here. Apologies for the rambling response.

Comment: @Broneironaut Yes and Yes. He's often using it when I want it and it still annoys the hell out of me even if I'm not going to use it. I haven't asked yet  to use it because there's no way to work in with him - the routine is continuous. Therefore my request would be essentially for him to pause his workout for me. I'm not sure how to tactfully ask him to do that, thus my question. Thanks for your response!

Comment: @Z.King Especially if it's continuous, you can just politely ask him to move. If he was doing sets in the squat rack, it might be more considerate to ask him between sets, but if he's taking up something you need for ages you're allowed to interrupt him. It's inappropriate to spend a significant length of time misusing equipment other people need, and he can probably take thirty seconds to listen to you and move. Something like "Excuse me, are you using the squat rack for your routine?"  should be fine. I can write this a little more eloquently as an answer later.

Comment: @SeanDuggan While it is about communicating with somebody else, it is also very particular to gym routines and etiquette. I can't say how on topic that is, but it seems that it is a better question for fitness experts than IPS.

Comment: @Broneironaut: I suppose I could see that point of view.

Comment: @Broneironaut - I agree with Sean, in that it would probably get good responses on IPS, but on both sites I think the answer would be along the lines of "1. Ask politely. 2. Inform gym staff"

Comment: @Broneironaut I agree that your comment could be extended to become a good answer. I did my leg day today and luckily the person in question was not around (YES!!!), but these comments should help next time he's hogging the squat rack AND I need it. Thanks

Comment: This should be moved to Interpersonal Stack maybe?

Answer (score 2):

talk to the guy. let  him know that there are other people that want to use the space. show him some other exercises that he can do away from the machine.